# get only xml data from text file using python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, etl, data-extraction

I have a text file where I have some XML data and some HTML data. Both start with "<". Now I want to extract only XML data and save it in another file. How can I do it?

File example:

```
xyz data:
<note>
<to>john</to>
<from>doe</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>

xyz data
<bold>xyz</bold>

text 
text 
text

<bold>xyz</bold>

again XML data
```

Note: This file is in .txt format.

Comment: How can you tell which section is XML and which one is HTML? They use the same tag syntax..

Comment: There is no such thing as "text mixed with XML". Either it's XML, then it can be parsed with an XML parser. Or it's something else, for example text with `<` and `>` sprinkled in various locations. That's what you have. What you can try to do is parse this with an HTML parser and then look at the resulting DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would treat your whole input not as XML, but as an HTML fragment. HTML can contain non-standard elements, so `<note>` etc. is fine.

For convenience I suggest `pyquery` ([link](https://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/)) to deal with HTML. It works pretty much the same way as jQuery, so if you've worked with that before, it should be familiar.

It's pretty straight-forward. Load your data, wrap it in `"<html></html>"`, parse it, query it.

```py
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

data = """xyz data:
<note>
<to>john</to>
<from>doe</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>

xyz data
<bold>xyz</bold>

text 
text 
text

<bold>xyz</bold>

again XML data"""

doc = pq(f"<html><body>{data}</body></html>")
note = doc.find("note")

print(note.find("body").text())
```

which prints `"Don't forget me this weekend!"`.